# Default value for javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a library with an `AppConfig` class.

What would be the best way to inform other developers using this library what the default values in `AppConfig` are?

One idea I have is to mention it in javadoc, something like this:

```
public class AppConfig {
   private int someSetting = 50;

   /**
    * This setting does something.
    *
    * @default 50
    */
   public int setSomeSetting(int someSetting){
      this.someSetting = someSetting;
   }
}
```

But what are the actual best practices for this scenario?

(as I believe `@default` is not really a supported tag)

Comment: It would be better to create some constant like so:


`public static final int DEFAULT_SETTING = 50;`, and then have `someSetting = DEFAULT_SETTING;` to initialise it.

That way it's abundantly clear what the default is and why it's being set to that specific value.

Comment: @patrick-hainge That might make clear what the default is -- but how would it make clear *why* it's being set to that value?

Comment: It clarifies *why* in the sense that rather than seeing `x = 50` and having to look at documentation or comments to find out why `x` starts out as `50`, we see `x = THE_DEFAULT_VALUE` and immediately understand what's going on.

Comment: @patrick-hainge and of course, it would be visible in the javadoc - field summary, so it is documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct; there is no such annotation.

From there: this is "pure style" only; meaning: javadoc is fine - you do whatever works for you; respectively the team of people around you that will be using this class.

The really tricky question though: **where** to put that piece of information?! You see: when a user of the class `setSomeSetting()` ... you **already** applied that default value.

In other words: you are probably using those defaults within your constructor. So you should rather tell the user right in the "class javadoc" about those defaults; and probably their values.

Like:

```
/**
 * ... Provides properties x, y,z; with defaults 50, 100, 150
 */
public class Foo {
  public final int BAR_DEFAULT = 50; 
  private int bar = BAR_DEFAULT;

  public void setBar(int newBar) { bar = newBar; }
```

Comment: I would just add my two cents about "_Where to put that piece of information_" that this could/should be in the getter instead of the setter. We don't care what was the value when we update it. And of course using a constant would be quite clear since they would be visible in the javadoc (based on the access)

Comment: @GhostCat What if the Config class contains 20 or 50 variables? Should I list all those default values in the class javadoc?

Comment: @AxelH That seems to be more correct and intuitive. However, in this case the developers using this library are passing the config to the library which will make us of it -- basically nobody except the library will ever call the getters.

The developers using this library are usually gonna create an AppConfig object, maybe change a few values, then pass it to the library and use the library.

Comment: @user2015253 Hum, what are you doing with a `Config` class that will not provide a getter ? The fields are `private` so hidden to the rest. And `Config` those not say that there is any logic behind. But even without that, using the constant solve the problem. **And last thing, if there is not getter, you don't care about the default value since nobody will use it.**

Comment: @user2015253 If that class lists 20 or 50 variables, then your problem is not how to document the defaults. Then your problem is a potentially broken design. You see, having a "flat list" of numeric values, that only by their name try to transport their *meaning* isn't really a good concept. But in order to work on that problem, you would probably have to ask another question. Or we could meet up in some chat room and talk about it.

Comment: @user2015253 Regarding the "where" - that was just a suggestion. I would prefer that people understand **all** them defaults when creating a new Foo instance. But that is the thing: this is informal, style only. There is no right or wrong; just that solution that works best for you.

Comment: @AxelH Getters do exist, but they are usually only called by the library. For example, if this was a HTTP library, then one of the settings you could provide is the timeout for http requests or a logging level for errors/warnings. As a developer using this library you would usually only set some of these settings, but never really get it. -- However, I like the use of constants. Probably gonna go that way :)

Comment: @GhostCat I see. In my case there are like 10 config variables, but there *might* be more sometime in the future. This is quite a big library, so having quite a few config settings wouldn't be too odd. Thanks for your help :)